# Magento 2.1: How to use getParam('param')?

Tags: magento-2.1, controllers

I have a code: 
`$params = unserialize(base64_decode($this->getRequest()->getParam('params')));`
I don't know how to find out **params** any where. Could you show how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Have you set value for params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume that your url has the format like:

```
<protocol>://<domain-name>/<frontname>/<controller_name>/<action_name>/<param_name>/<param_value>?<query_string_name>=<query_string_value>
```

So example:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/example/id/1/?testing=1
```

To get all params in the url use:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

This will return an array in the format:

```
Array
(
    [<param_name>] => <param_value>
)
```

So in case of the example url it should return something like:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [testing] => 1
)
```

To get a particular param value use:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam(<param_name>);
```

Example:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

This will return the value `1`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have one more question. I want to get param for all the product. To get all params in the url use:

`$this->getRequest()->getParams();`  Example: `http://192.168.1.xx/theme_magento/men/tops-men.html?style_general=117 `. How to get specific **params** for the product?

Comment: @MinhTamPham I could not understand the question. Can you ask a new question and add a little bit more details on this ?

Comment: I have this page: [http://magento2.emthemes.com/everything/women/tops-women.html] . When i click on the fillter on the left i will get this link: http://magento2.emthemes.com/everything/women/tops-women.html?cat=23 . It has <param_value> = tops-women.html, <query_string_name>=cat, <query_string_value>=23. In generality,  what is the <param_value> for that?

Comment: Example: I have code into Controller, <param_value>=data(`$data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('data');`):  `class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
 public function execute()
 {        
  $this->_view->loadLayout();

  $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('data');
  $data = base64_decode($data);
  $data = json_decode($data);
  $result = array();`......

Comment: ..................`if($data){
   foreach($data as $key => $value)
   {
       $result[$key] = $value;
   }
   $block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock($result['type']);
   $block->setData('current_url',$data->current_url);
   if(!$this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('formkey')){
    $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey','formkey');
   }
   //echo "<pre>";echo $block->toHtml();die; 
   $block->setData($result); 
   $block->setData('uniqueId',uniqid());
   $this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
  }
 }
}`

Comment: I'm so sorry!!! I'm a new member. I will improve for the editor soon.

Comment: @MinhTamPham Can you separate new question and add these details there ?